# Uniform convergence of Binomial series on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider the Binomial series

\begin{align} (1+x)^\alpha =\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{\alpha\choose k}x^k,\;\text{for }\;x\in \Bbb{R}\;\text{and}\;\alpha\in\Bbb{R} \end{align}
I want to show that it converges uniformly on $\Bbb{R}$.

However, it can be shown by D'Alembert's Ratio test that the following series converges absolutely \begin{align} F(\alpha) =\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}{\alpha\choose k}x^k,\;\text{for fixed}\;|x|<1\;\text{and}\;\alpha\in\Bbb{R} \end{align}
since \begin{align} \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{^\alpha C_{k+1}}{^\alpha C_{k}}\right|=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{\alpha-k}{k+1}\right|=|x|<1,\;\text{for fixed}\;|x|<1\;\text{and}\;\alpha\in\Bbb{R} \end{align}
**QUESTION:** How do I get uniform convergence of $F$ on $\Bbb{R}$ from there? Alternatively, if there's any other way of showing that it converges uniformly on $\Bbb{R}$, I will appreciate.

Comment: It won't converge uniformly on $\Bbb R$ (unless $\alpha=0$). It may or may not converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$, but that will depend on the value of $\alpha$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: But [William R. Wade-Introduction to Analysis-Pearson](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Analysis-Pearson-New-International-ebook/dp/B00IZ0QU1U) tells me it converges uniformly on $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: In line 2 you say 'for $|x| <1$' and in line 3 you ask for uniform convergence of $\mathbb R$

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Sorry, I corrected the error.

Answer (score 1):

A series of the type $\sum a_k x^{k}$ cannot converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$ unless $a_k=0$ for all but finite number of $k$'s. (This is because the general term does not tend to $0$ uniformly).